# Align radio buttons css issue

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styles

I am trying to align my custom radio buttons in a line but I am having an issue. If the text is really long but radio button overlap each other. I don't want to assign a fix width to any of them. Also, I need to have `.radio .custom` styling there if I want to change the border of the radio button for error handling. I am open to changing the html structure but I need the Text to be inside `custom` span. I can get rid of the inner-span if needed.

I have tried using:

```
display:flex;
```

on `label`

but it ended up giving me each option right over each other.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.radio span.custom > span {
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.radio .custom {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.radio input:checked + .custom:before {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
}
.radio input + .custom:after {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.checkbox input:checked .custom {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="custom"><span>Onasasasase</span></span>
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="custom"><span>Two</span></span>
</label>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/37355e7x/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.  I simplified your HTML slightly (removed extra nested `span`) and used the following CSS.

Your custom button is 18px square, so I allowed for a 25px margin on the child element `span.custom`.

This allows space for the `:before` pseudo-element that appears to the left of `.custom`.

I colored the background on the `label` so that you can see the unchecked button, but otherwise, you can mark-up gives you a lot of control over the borders, spacing and so on.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #F0F0F0; // for demo only
}

.radio .custom {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.radio input + .custom:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.radio input:checked + .custom:before {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="custom">One is very long</span>
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="custom">Two</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped everything in a parent div and made it a flexbox, while centering it. Seems to work for me.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="custom"><span>Onasasasase</span></span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="custom"><span>Two</span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```